# Target div to hide with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to toggle a div on click of an element within that div. I'm not sure if I target properly.

```
$(".clicker").click(function() {
   $(this).parent(".container").next(".hiddenDiv").toggle();
});

<div class="container">
     <div class="textBox"></div>
     <div class="clicker"></div>
</div>
<div class="hiddenDiv"></div>

<div class="container">
     <div class="textBox"></div>
     <div class="clicker"></div>
</div>
<div class="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you missing the period in `.next(".hiddenDiv")`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, just a typo. I did have it there.